# How to authenticate android user POST request with Django REST API?

Tags: java, android, python, django, authentication

As of now, I have a Django REST API and everything is hunky dory for the web app, wherein I have implemented User Auth in the backend. The "login_required" condition serves well for the web app, which is cookie based.

I have an Android app now that needs to access the same API. I am able to sign in the user. What I need to know is how to authenticate every user when they make GET/POST request to my views?

My research shows a couple of solutions:
1) Cookie-backed sessions
2) Send username and password with every GET/POST request(might not be secure)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Django REST Framework in which case TokenAuthentication might be suitable.
From the docs:

> This authentication scheme uses a simple token-based HTTP
>   Authentication scheme. Token authentication is appropriate for
>   client-server setups, such as native desktop and mobile clients

You don't need to pre-generate the tokens as clients can ask for one using the built-in view `obtain_auth_token` which you configure in your urls.py.

Once the client has obtained the token for the session they can provide it on subsequent API calls using the `Authorization:` HTTP header.

Check out the docs for more info: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 3):

> HTTP Basic authentication (BA) implementation is the simplest
>   technique for enforcing access controls to web resources because it
>   doesn't require cookies, session identifier and login pages. Rather,
>   HTTP Basic authentication uses static, standard HTTP headers which
>   means that no handshakes have to be done in anticipation

To read more and get an idea what you need to do on server and client side to implement, read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

I have used different REST java frameworks and all of them provides simple APIs to add Basic authentication header addition and retrieval.

For Django, here are some useful code snippets:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the Django Sessions middleware, which will set a cookie with a django session_id. On the following requests, the sessions middleware will set an attribute on your request object called user and you can then test if user is authenticated by request.user.is_authenticated()  ( or login_required decorator) . Also, you can set the session timeout to whatever you like in the settings.

This middleware is enabled in default django settings.